# n-way `span` on sequences

Tags: scala

Given a sequence of elements and a predicate `p`, I would like to produce a sequence of sequences such that, in each subsequence, either all elements satisfy `p` or the sequence has length `1`. Additionally, calling `.flatten` on the result should give me back my original sequence (so no re-ordering of elements).

For instance, given:

```
val l = List(2, 4, -6, 3, 1, 8, 7, 10, 0)
val p = (i : Int) => i % 2 == 0
```

I would like `magic(l,p)` to produce:

```
List(List(2, 4, -6), List(3), List(1), List(8), List(7), List(10, 0))
```

I know of `.span`, but that method stops the first time it encounters a value that doesn't satisfy `p` and just returns a pair.

Below is a candidate implementation. It does what I want, but, well, makes we want to cry. I would love for someone to come up with something slightly more idiomatic.

```
def magic[T](elems : Seq[T], p : T=>Boolean) : Seq[Seq[T]] = {
  val loop = elems.foldLeft[(Boolean,Seq[Seq[T]])]((false,Seq.empty)) { (pr,e) =>
    val (lastOK,s) = pr
    if(lastOK && p(e)) {
      (true, s.init :+ (s.last :+ e))
    } else {
      (p(e), s :+ Seq(e))
    }
  }
  loop._2
}
```

(Note that I do not particularly care about preserving the actual type of the `Seq`.)

Comment: A better name than `magic` might be `spans`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not use `foldLeft`. It's just a simple recursion of `span` with a special rule if the head doesn't match the predicate:

```
def magic[T](elems: Seq[T], p: T => Boolean): Seq[Seq[T]] = 
  elems match {
    case Seq() => Seq()
    case Seq(head, tail @ _*) if !p(head) => Seq(head) +: magic(tail, p)
    case xs => 
      val (prefix, rest) = xs span p
      prefix +: magic(rest, p)
  }
```

You could also do it tail-recursive, but you need to remember to reverse the output if you're prepending (as is sensible):

```
def magic[T](elems: Seq[T], p: T => Boolean): Seq[Seq[T]] = {
  def iter(elems: Seq[T], out: Seq[Seq[T]]) : Seq[Seq[T]] = 
    elems match {
      case Seq() => out.reverse
      case Seq(head, tail @ _*) if !p(head) => iter(tail, Seq(head) +: out)
      case xs => 
        val (prefix, rest) = xs span p
        iter(rest, prefix +: out)
    }
  iter(elems, Seq())
}
```

Comment: This answer is probably the best. (Either method, depending on your performance needs)

Answer (score 3):

For this task you can use `takeWhile` and `drop` combined with a little pattern matching an recursion:

```
def magic[T](elems : Seq[T], p : T=>Boolean) : Seq[Seq[T]] = {
  def magic(elems: Seq[T], result: Seq[Seq[T]]): Seq[Seq[T]] = elems.takeWhile(p) match {
    // if elems is Nil, we have a result
    case Nil if elems.isEmpty => result

    // if it's not, but we don't get any values from takeWhile, we take a single elem
    case Nil => magic(elems.tail, result :+ Seq(elems.head))

    // takeWhile gave us something, so we add it to the result
    // and drop as many elements from elems, as takeWhile gave us
    case xs => magic(elems.drop(xs.size), result :+ xs)
  }

  magic(elems, Seq())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using a fold:

```
def magicFilter[T](seq: Seq[T], p: T => Boolean): Seq[Seq[T]] = {
  val (filtered, current) = (seq foldLeft (Seq[Seq[T]](), Seq[T]())) {
    case ((filtered, current), element) if p(element)       => (filtered, current :+ element)
    case ((filtered, current), element) if !current.isEmpty => (filtered :+ current :+ Seq(element), Seq())
    case ((filtered, current), element)                     => (filtered :+ Seq(element), Seq())
  }
  if (!current.isEmpty) filtered :+ current else filtered
}
```